# ListView Not updating when using setText()

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have a list view where the user can add several rows with certain financial numbers.  The `ListView` is in a `ListFragment` called from a `FragmentActivity`.

In the `ActionBar` (in the `FragmentActivity`), there is a button that opens up a regular `Activity` where the user can add the numbers.  Once they hit submit on that page, it finishes that Activity, it calls `onActivityResult()` where I simply do a `FragmentTransaction` (on the same `ListFragment` mentioned above) to refresh the page and the new row is displayed.

Here is important part: If you click on the row, it opens up a dialog where the user can change their numbers.  I do an update to the SQLite database (which works) and also try to update the `TextView` of the `ListView` row they are changing.  However, nothing happens.

Here is code on the update (I included only one field but there are actually multiple `EditText` fields and `TextView`s that do same thing):

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, final int position, long id) {
    final Debt debt = values.get(position);

    final long boxId = debt.getId();
    BoxName = debt.getName();

    // set up dialog
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());

    // set up text
    et1 = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    et1.setText(BoxName);

    Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

        BoxName = et1.getText().toString();


        datasource.updateDebt(boxId, BoxName, BoxBalance, BoxApr,
                BoxPayment, BoxSApr, BoxSAprTime, BoxDay);

        dialog.dismiss();

            // when I log firstVisible and position; correct numbers appear
        int firstVisible = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        View rowView = lv.getChildAt(position - firstVisible);


        TextView newName = ((TextView) rowView
                        .findViewById(R.id.labelName));

             // this is line that does not work
        newName.setText(BoxName);

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Note: `Adapter`, `Listview` are both static but I have tried with and without with same result.

Comment: how does your adapter interact with the datasource?

Comment: Hmmmm... I don't see where it does. Nothing like `adapter.setName(name)`

Comment: @LenaBru  That was the problem; you can write that as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to update your adapter before calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

do not update the ui manually

Comment: Thanks; this is what I did.  I also removed all the code that directly setText'ed the row itself and only changed the adapter (the proper way I guess).